# Sub-Website in IIS - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, virtual-directory

I have a asp.net website in the IIS which is available on internet as www.xyz.com now I have been asked to prepare another website which will be accessed via www.xyz.com/abc.

For this, do I need to create a virtual directory under the website folder XYZ in IIS? or is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Logic says that would be a part of the existing site or at least very closely related. Is it?

Comment: @Lazarus: Yes, it is something like new modification in the existing website.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to make the subdirectory an IIS application.

Keep in mind that inner apps like yours will be inheriting configurations from the top-most web configuration, so be careful clearing those settings you don't want in the child applications.

Comment: +1 for noting the config sharing, you can get into some crazy configuration issues because of it.

Comment: What I am planning to create a individual website, complile and publish it. Then I'll create a virtual directory under the website. Is it ok?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I want to notice again you can have configuration problems, because ASP.NET apps overloads their configurations. I mean, if you have one, and you put another the second as a child of the first, that second will inherit configurations from the first. Be careful!! (check this article: http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/how-to-disable-web-config-inheritance-for-child-applications-in-subfolders-in-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: @Matias: Thanks for the warning. Is it like I may receive errors like different versions of dll in different apps. or ajax failue? Do I have use <remove> and <clear> tag everytime I face this kind of error?

Comment: Oops ! I didn't read the last part of the article. I got my answer. Thanks

Comment: @Matias, the link you mentioned in your comment is broken. Could you please re-add a working link to the article?

Comment: Application != Site (!= "Sub Site", as extension).

Answer (score 1):

Yes a virtual directory will work, however note that if abc is a full-blown app you will have to add it as an application not as a virtual directory

Comment: Site abc is added as a website in IIS. I'll right click on the website icon and create a virtual directory under it. Is it fine?