# Is it possible to integrate two .NET Applications (1 WebForm and 1 MVC) into one domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I originally programmed two separate. NET applications (1 WebForm and 1 MVC 5) that originally were going to be on separate domains. I'm now trying to integrate both applications on a single portal on a single domain that will likely be a MVC Web Application. Ideally I would like to use subdomains to keep them separate.

I've figured that there's 2 options to make this happen but even then I don't know if #1 is even  feasible.

1) Host each application on separate subdomains (ex: WebForm.domain.com and MVC.domain.com) while having the main portal on the default domain  (domain.com).

2) Rewrite the WebForm application into a MVC application and just merge the two projects.

I'm open to any and all suggestions

Comment: Option 1 is feasible and time saving but in my opinion option 2 is better approach than option 1.

Comment: Good to know about option 1. The main reason why I'm trying to avoid option 2 is because the Web form app is a single page application with tons of postback triggers that use buttons to update a few grid views.

Comment: You can jQuery grids(jQ grids for eg) with MVC framework. It would be easy to transform from webform to MVC if you want.

Comment: Okay awesome thank you for the suggestion. I'll do more research on both options. It sounds for scalability reasons that it would be preferred to integrate every current and future application using the MVC Framework

Comment: Possible answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747576/sub-website-in-iis-asp-net

Comment: It is possible by useing subdomains, different ports, web-site headers or one site with two application (mydomain.com/webapp1 and mydomain.com/webapp2). What do you want? What is your hosting server?

Comment: yes you can host both applications at same domain by creating virtual directory on IIS the URL for first application will look like www.xyz.com and the URL for second application will be www.xyz.com/directoryname